# How to force a render script kernel to run on only GPU on Nexus5 device, android-4.4.4_r1

Tags: android, renderscript

I am working on Nexus 5 device running android-4.4.4_r1.
I am using a simple gray scale image application which converts a color image to gray scale using render script kernel.

But I want to run the kernel only on the GPU. How can I make sure the kernel runs only on the GPU at run time from render script level of android frame work level. Please give me some pointers.

I need this to compare performance between CPU GPU processing of the kernel.

Regards
Skuanr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force RS to run on any particular processor of the device. That is one of the design goals/decisions.